# Ruby on NixOS -- FFI Gem installation failing when building native extensions

Tags: ruby, nixos

I am a Rubyist of many years. I cannot determine what's missing to prevent FFI from installing.

Here is the error from the `make.out` file (gotta love that name):

```
make[3]: *** [Makefile:1048: libffi_convenience.la] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/dw/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/ffi-1.9.23/ext/ffi_c/libffi-x86_64-linux'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:1309: all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/dw/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/ffi-1.9.23/ext/ffi_c/libffi-x86_64-linux'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:617: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/dw/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/ffi-1.9.23/ext/ffi_c/libffi-x86_64-linux'
make: *** [libffi.mk:9: "/home/dw/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/ffi-1.9.23/ext/ffi_c/libffi-x86_64-linux"/.libs/libffi_convenience.a] Error 2

make failed, exit code 2
```

I checked nixpkgs and saw `libffi-3.2.1` and `pure-ffi-0.14` were available. I installed both. I still getting the error.

Comment: `make.out` LMAO! You mentioned installing two libraries in an attempt to provide the necessary dependencies for building a Ruby gem. NixOS takes a different approach here: derivations must specify their dependencies. What this means in practice is that installed libraries are not exposed in the way needed for other libraries and applications can find them. So when you try to build a binary outside of Nix, the linker is simply unable to find the libraries you've installed. In contrast, applications you install explicitly get added to your "user environment" which makes when accessible to you.

Comment: generally, `rubygems` and `bundler` handle these dependencies. Are you saying on NixOS the preference is to use `nix` and Derivations? I am aware from earlier attempted `npm` package installs that there is some friction when there is another thing that tries to handle dependencies. Is this similar?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the same issue as with npm. It's not really NixOS, but rather Nix that *requires* (rather than prefers) that you specify dependencies using Nix. There's some tooling for compiling gems with Nix: https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#sec-language-ruby

Answer (score 0):

The first option is to use [bundix](https://github.com/manveru/bundix). It uses a global override file to inject system dependencies: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/development/ruby-modules/gem-config/default.nix

Most important gems should be found there including the [ffi](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/development/ruby-modules/gem-config/default.nix#L107) gem, that you are trying to install.

If you don't want to/can use bundix, the alternative is a nix-shell that gives you the correct build environment.

For the ffi gem you can also borrow the code from nixpkgs's gem-config:

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};
stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "env";
  buildInputs = [
    ffi pkgconfig
  ];
}
```

Then just run `nix-shell` in the project. This step can be also automated using direnv's nix support.
Installing `ffi` via `nix-env` does not work because it does not set the  `NIX_CFLAGS_COMPILE` and `NIX_LDFLAGS` variable that is necessary for the ffi gem to find the correct header/libraries during compilation.

Comment: I didn't have any luck adding `ffi` to `buildInputs`, but `libffi` worked.